# Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
 Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:
```

I can find libcudnn.so.7 in /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/.Also, I have added the following path in my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I don not know why, I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason for this error is incompatibility between the TensorFlow version and the CUDA version. Try looking up which CUDA version to use with your TF version (or vice-versa). Alternatively, try going one version up and down in both to see if they match.

Comment: Thank you. I upgrade tesorflow-gpu==1.14 to  tesorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0